# Podfile doesn't install selected branch

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, branch, podfile

Hi I'm trying to add https://github.com/fxm90/GradientLoadingBar/tree/feature/notch-gradient-loading-bar in my Xcode project , but when I specify
`pod 'GradientLoadingBar', :git => 'https://github.com/fxm90/GradientLoadingBar', :branch => 'feature/notch-gradient-loading-bar'` in my Podfile

doesn't download me the branch. I also tried with `:branch => 'notch-gradient-loading-bar'` , but also unsuccessfully. It downloads something, but is not the branch that I need and I cannot implement the new feature `NotchGradientLoadingBar`

`let notchGradientLoadingBar = NotchGradientLoadingBar(height: 6)` gives me an error `Use of unresolved identifier 'NotchGradientLoadingBar'`

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell there appears to be only one branch (see [here](https://github.com/fxm90/GradientLoadingBar/branches/all) for reference). You need only checkout the standard branch and from there you can implement NotchGradientLoadingBar using the documentation found [here](https://github.com/fxm90/GradientLoadingBar#how-to-use).

In my testing, after adding the main branch to your Xcode project and importing GradientLoadingBar, you should be able to use `let notchGradientLoadingBar = NotchGradientLoadingBar(height: 6)` with no problem.